# Matching one of in array in search filter in mongodb

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

Sorry, tried to search, but the normal filter just overtakes normal queries, so even if it's answered somewhere I am struggling a bit.

I have a code like this:

```js
const searchResults = await ProductWithBrandModel.aggregate([
    {
        $search: {
            index: 'product-brand-search',
            compound: {
                filter: [{
                    text: {
                        query: request.query.color, // is an array
                        path: 'metadata.colors' // is an array
                    }
                }],
                should: [
                    {
                        autocomplete: {
                            query: request.query.query,
                            path: 'title',

                        }
                    },
                    {
                        autocomplete: {
                            query: request.query.query,
                            path: 'description',

                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
]);
```

The issue with the code is that the metadata.colors is an array. This same goes for the input ( request.query.color ).

I want the array to match at least one of the other, so ["blue","black"] will match ["blue","green"] ( order unimportant )

I checked documentation https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/compound/#filter-examples , but it doesn't really go over the whole array in in array thing. Especially at least one of, so now the query returns empty results.

I checked documentation https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/compound/#filter-examples

I also checked if there are actually products that match query.